# Ruling out the existence of a strange polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Does there exist a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that

$$\displaystyle f(a,b) > 0 \text{ for all } a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$$

and

$$\displaystyle \liminf_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) = -\infty?$$

In other words, does there exist a polynomial $f$ which takes on positive values at every integer point, but still there exists a sequence $(x_k, y_k)$ of real pairs such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(x_k, y_k) = -\infty$?

Note that if such a sequence exists, the norm of its elements must tend to infinity. This is because $f$ is continuous, and therefore the image of any compact set under $f$ is necessarily compact, and thus in particular must be bounded.

Comment: What about $(x^2+1)(5y(y-1)+1)$?

Comment: Ah yes, I was contemplating a similar example but it fell short of producing a counter-example. I'll accept this as an answer if you write it.

Comment: Is this a Math Olympiad problem?

Comment: @PabloH No, it is not, at least not one that I am aware of. This arose from a research problem I am thinking about.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The polynomial $f(x,y)=(x^2+1)(5y^2+5y+1)\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is an example. Note that $5y^2+5y+1>0$ for $y\in\mathbb{Z}$, but $5y^2+5y+1<0$ at $y=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Your comment has a minus sign but your answer doesn't... did you intend them to match?

Comment: Either works. I just thought that $5y^2+5y+1$ looked a bit more aesthetically pleasing that $5y(y-1)+1$.